# Como dar permissões para grupos de usuários no PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados, administração-postgresql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Todos os usuários cadastrados que forem membros do “ACESSO SITE” vão ter as mesmas permissões.

Criei um grupo de usuários(Group Roles) no PostgreSQL chamado "ACESSO SITE" para colocar todos os usuários(Login Roles) dos sites e sistemas que vão ter permissões para pesquisar, inserir, atualizar e deletar informações. Quando criar um usuário para determinado sistema ou site quero apenas dizer que ele faz parte do Grupo(Group Roles) "ACESSO SITE" e o mesmo herdar todas as permissões do grupo definidas anteriormente sem que precise ficar dando permissões toda vez que criar um usuário novo.

Como posso configurar o Group Roles "ACESSO SITE" dando permissão uma única vez e posteriormente só ir alocando os novos usuários no grupo?

Answer (score 1):

Cria o grupo acesso_site:

```
CREATE ROLE acesso_site NOINHERIT LOGIN PASSWORD '1';
```

Define as permissões à ele:

```
GRANT SELECT
  ON public.estoque TO acesso_site;

  GRANT INSERT
  ON public.estoque TO acesso_site;

GRANT USAGE
  ON public.estoque_codigo_seq TO acesso_site;
```

Cria um usuario, dentro do grupo `acesso_site`:

```
  CREATE ROLE usuario1 LOGIN PASSWORD '1' IN ROLE acesso_site;
```

creio que seja apenas isso

Comment: Em CREATE ROLE acesso_site NOINHERIT LOGIN PASSWORD '1'; porquê preciso colocar LOGIN PASSWORD '1 esse código não é para criar o grupo dos usuários?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```sql
CREATE ROLE acesso_site INHERIT NOLOGIN NOSUPERUSER;
CREATE USER usuario1 WITH LOGIN NOSUPERUSER PASSWORD 'xxx' INHERIT IN ROLE acesso_site;
```

Depois é só colocar as permissões nos objetos como:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT ON TABLE public.<TABELA> TO acesso_site;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHAME <SCHEMA> TO acesso_site;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION <FUNCTION> TO acesso_site;
```